# Resolution of Router v8 vs v7

Tags: here-api

I've been using the HERE Routing API v7 for quite a while and how now tried to upgrade my app to v8. One marked difference is that for my test route the API v7 came up with about 900 waypoints, whereas the v8 API gave me almost 7000!

The routes themselves look fairly identical, but the resolution of the V8 API appears to be much higher. Is there a way to reduce the resolution to the old level, which was plenty for my application?

One difference on my side is that with the V8 API I am using flexible polyline by going through all returned sections, decoding the polyline and appending it to my route. With the V7 API I got a "shape" array within the returned route, so no polyline and no iterating through sections. It seemed a lot simpler.

There is a parameter "resolution" in the V7 API, which I usually set to 10. This parameter doesn't seem to exist in V8.

Comment: Can you share your http requests?

Comment: Sure:
`https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=***&transportMode=truck&return=polyline&origin=56.76594924926758,9.693559646606445&destination=54.04389953613281,9.9795503616333`